# Map in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a visual force page where i all the display account records.I used a apex:pageBlockTable to display all the account records using map.Before displaying the records i wanted to display the spinner using a apex:actionFunction.I am displaying spinner under a separate apex:outputpanel and i am displaying all the account records in another apex:outputpannel.But i am getting a error saying "Map key 1 not found in map
Error is in expression '{!mapOfAccounts[accountCurrentPageNumber]}' in component apex:pageBlockTable in page displayaccounts".Can anyone explain me why i am getting this error when i am not rendering that apex:outputpanel that contains map.

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account" extensions="DisplayAccountsController">
<apex:form>
    <apex:outputPanel  rendered="{!isSuccess}">
    <apex:actionFunction name="loadPageContent" action="{!callRetrieveAccounts}" oncomplete="stop();" status="loading"/>
     <apex:actionFunction name="stopLoading" action="{!stopSpinner}" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
 <apex:actionStatus id="loading">
    <apex:facet name="start">
    <div style="z-index: 1000; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background-color: black; opacity: 0.25">
        
    </div>
    <div style="z-index: 1001; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; padding: 1em; margin: -2em -10em; width: 20em; height: 32px; background: white; border-radius: 5px">
        <img src="/img/loading32.gif" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-right: 1em" />
        Loading...
    </div>
    </apex:facet>
</apex:actionStatus>
<script>
    loadPageContent();
    function stop(){
        stopLoading();
    }
</script> 
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(isSuccess)}">
   <apex:pageBlock title="Accounts"  id="capitalCommitementSection">
        <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!mapOfAccounts[accountCurrentPageNumber]}" var="acc" id="commitmentsRepeat">
                <apex:column style="width: 100px">
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <a class="selectToggle" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleSelectAll();">Deselect All</a>
                    </apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column style="width: 300px"> 
                    <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Name}" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:commandButton value="<" rerender="capitalCommitementSection" action="{!previousCapitalCommitmenttList}"
            disabled="{!prev}" />
        <apex:commandButton value=">"  rerender="capitalCommitementSection" action="{!nextCapitalCommitmentList}"
            disabled="{!nxt}" />
        <apex:outputText value="Showing page {!accountCurrentPageNumber} of {!sizeOfAccountMap}" />
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form></apex:page>
```

controller:

```
public class DisplayAccountsController {
public Map<Integer,List<Account>> mapOfAccounts {get;set;}
public  Integer accountCurrentPageNumber {get;set;}
public Integer accountsPageSize{get;set;}
public  Integer counter {get;set;}
public  Boolean isSuccess {get;set;}
public Boolean IsEnabled=true; 
public Integer sizeOfAccountMap {
    get {
        return mapOfAccounts.size();
    }
}
public DisplayAccountsController(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
    counter = 0;
    accountCurrentPageNumber = 1;
    accountsPageSize = 400;
    mapOfAccounts = new Map<Integer,List<Account>>();
}
public void callRetrieveAccounts(){
    isSuccess = true;
    retrieveAccounts(); 
}
public void stopSpinner(){
    isSuccess = false;
}
public void retrieveAccounts(){
    List<Account> listOfAccountsPerPage = new List<Account>();
    Integer totalRecordsProcessed = 0;
    Integer counter = 0;
    Integer pageNumber = 0;
    List<Account> listOfAccounts = [select id,Name from account];
    for(Account acc: listOfAccounts){
        totalRecordsProcessed++;
        counter++;
        listOfAccountsPerPage.add(acc);
        if (counter == accountsPageSize) {
            pageNumber = pageNumber + 1;
            mapOfAccounts.put(pageNumber, listOfAccountsPerPage);
            counter = 0;
            listOfAccountsPerPage = new List<Account>();
        } 
        else if (totalRecordsProcessed == listOfAccounts.size()) {
            pageNumber = pageNumber + 1;
            mapOfAccounts.put(pageNumber, listOfAccountsPerPage);
        }
    }
    if(totalRecordsProcessed == listOfAccounts.size() ){
        counter = 5;
    }
}
public boolean getprev() {
    if (accountCurrentPageNumber == 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public boolean getnxt() {
    if (accountCurrentPageNumber == mapOfAccounts.size())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public void previousCapitalCommitmenttList() {
    accountCurrentPageNumber = accountCurrentPageNumber - 1;
}
public void nextCapitalCommitmentList() {
    accountCurrentPageNumber = accountCurrentPageNumber + 1;
}
```

}

error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `rendered` attributes are backwards. `isSuccess` is initially null, which is treated as a false value, so the spinner isn't shown, and your table is. You defaulted to page 1, but there is no page 1 in your constructor:

```
public DisplayAccountsController(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
    counter = 0;
    accountCurrentPageNumber = 1;
    accountsPageSize = 400;
    mapOfAccounts = new Map<Integer,List<Account>>();
}
```

Switch the rendered attribute so that the spinner is `rendered="{!NOT(isSuccess)}"`, and the table is `rendered="{!isSuccess}"`.

Also, because you used an action function, the spinner won't actually show while `retrieveAccounts` is running, because it takes a full Apex transaction to refresh the page.

In fact, it would probably be better to simply use `apex:actionStatus` directly; use the `start` facet to show the loading and use the `stop` facet to show the table.

Either way, remember that you cannot show the table until the map is populated with data.